# Using a rest parameter before the last parameter in function definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My problem is best explained with a simple code example:

```
function doThing(a, ...b, c) {
   console.log(a, b, c)
}
doThing(1,2,3,4); // Expect "1 [2,3] 4"
```

This instead gives a syntax error `Unexpected token`, pointing to the comma after the `b` in the function definition.

Is it not possible to put a single parameter *after* a 'rested' parameter with ES6? If not, any idea why? It would be really useful for me. Thanks!

**Edit:** I initially thought that `doThing(a, ...b, c)` would be completely unambiguous, but I see now that `doThing(1,2,3)` would need an arbitrary rule to decide whether the `3` goes in `b` or `c` (i.e. if we pass a number of params that is less than or equal to the number of params in the function definition).

Comment: I think that rest operator need to be the last one.

Comment: The spread operator (what you mention) and the rest parameter (what you are (theoretically) using) are two different things. If you are asking what the reasons behind the rest parameter are (that it only can occur last), you better ask the language designers directly, at https://esdiscuss.org/.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks I thought that might be the case. I've already stumbled into a case where my example function would be useful, but maybe there's a better way to do it, or it just hasn't been considered by the ES people yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

developer.mozilla.org says:

> If the *last named argument* of a function is prefixed with ..., it becomes an array whose elements from 0 to theArgs.length are supplied by the actual arguments passed to the function.

Actually this feature of ES6 is called [*Rest parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) so it is meant to be the last in the list of parameters.

So this code will work:

```
function doThing(a, b, ...c) {
   console.log(a, b, c);
}
doThing(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: What does `do2()` output in the console for this example?

Comment: (Changed `do()` to `doThing()`, thanks) Okay, thanks for the link! Maybe I'll have to wait for es8...

Comment: @StuperUser, it outputs `1 2 [ 3, 4 ]`. The array `c` has 2 elements; 3 and 4.

Comment: Even though @JoeRocc accepted this answer, I don't see how this answers the question *"Is it not possible to put a single parameter after a 'rested' parameter with ES6? If not, any idea why?"*.

Comment: @FelixKling true, it doesn't answer the why part - an edit to my question sort of explains it I think. I'd be happy to edit it in to zegoline's question (but she/he hasn't accepted my last edit yet) or accept a better answer if it props up